# What happened around 2012~2013 in 3D printing field

Tags: history

Comparing trends show that 3D printing stepped over to another level around 2012~2013. Why?

[image: 3D printing vs 3D scanning]

[image: 3D printer vs 3D scanner]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A great story on the history of 3D printing is published by [3DSOURCED](https://www.3dsourced.com/guides/history-of-3d-printing/). It shows that the patents for FDM and SLA expired a few years earlier and the [RepRap](https://reprap.org/wiki/RepRap) 3D printer self replicating project became very popular. Also, 3D printer manufacturers emerged and electronics, software and parts became available at a larger scale, so that it was more affordable for a hobbyist to dive in.

Comment: Could the same happen to 3D scan field? I mean, regarding patents for example.

Comment: once the patents run out, possibly, but I don't think to the degree of 3D Printers, as there is less "fun" application in scanners - and sharing scanned items might come with a legal backlash that sharing self-made designs might not because you much easier violate copyright.

Comment: It’s not even just fewer ‘fun’ applications for a 3D scanner, there are arguably fewer practical applications as well. 3D printing slots into the usual engineering development loop rather nicely as a way to speed up prototyping, and that’s a large part of what helped make it so generically popular, but 3D scanning is far less universally useful in such a setting.

Comment: History, Anthropology and Archaeology use 3D scanners, merged with 3D model generation it slots in nicely there (as in re-creating damaged artifacts etc)

Answer (score 0):

Another opinion received:

> That’s the result of MakerBot and others promoting the tech to the general public for the first time after the patents expired. They were just running up stock prices to make a lot of money